# Вложенные функции в C

Tags: c, функции

1) Являются ли вложенные функции исключительно расширением компиляторов, или же они появились в стандарте `C11`?

2) Вложенная функция имеет доступ ко всему, что лежит перед ней в ее области определения. С одной стороны, это удобно, получается нечто, напоминающее лямбды, но с другой стороны - появляются сколькие проблемы.

Например, такие:

```
void a(const int _i)
{
    void b(void)
    {
        printf("_i: %i", _i);
    }
}

// Технически, мы можем вызвать b() за пределами a(),
// но тогда непонятно, к чему мы обратимся, используя _i.
```

Я хотел бы разобраться, что можно делать с такими функциями, а что нельзя.

PS. Понятно, что вложенные функции опасны и имеют неочевидные подводные камни, но в некоторых случаях альтернативные решения еще хуже (например, макросы). В определенных ситуациях бывает удобно вынести повторяющиеся действия во вложенные функции. Или, к примеру, задать обработчик прямо перед его использованием, например так:

```
FILE *f = fopen("data", "wb");
// ...

void handler(void *_n)
{
    list_node *n = (list_node*)_n;
    fwrite(n->data, n->size, 1, f);
}

list_for_each(list, handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Это расширение gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html
2. Имя вложенной функции имеет локальную область видимости, т.е. нельзя вызвать `b` за пределами `a`.

Comment: Напрямую нельзя, но ведь технически есть возможность вызвать функцию через ее адрес.

Comment: @MGNeo Да, но вас предупреждали: *If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, **all hell breaks loose**. If you try to call it after a containing scope level exits, and if it refers to some of the variables that are no longer in scope, **you may be lucky**, but it’s not wise to take the risk. If, however, the nested function does not refer to anything that has gone out of scope, you should be safe.*

Comment: с одной стороны хочется попробовать, а с другой есть опасение, что документация не врёт и Ад действительно разверзнется...